# Base on Date visibility condition in HyperLink using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Base on Date visibility condition in HyperLink using asp.net c#. I am not getting how to match the condidation. If EventDate less than today and equal to today date means visible false.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="http://mysite.in/registerForm.aspx" Visible='<%# Eval("DateofEvent").ToString() <= DateTime.Now %>' Text="Click here for registration" Target="_blank" />
```

EventDate is like that save in table.

```
2016-03-29 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Remove the `.ToString()` and cast it to `DateTime` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASPX:

```
Visible='<%#GetVisible(Eval("DateofEvent").ToString())%>'
```

And in the code behind:

```
public bool GetVisible(object value)
{
    if (Convert.ToDateTime(value) <= DateTime.Now)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you wouldn't convert the `DateTime` to a string you wouldn't need to parse it back to `DateTime`. Even if it works today it might cause localization issues in future. So remove the `.ToString()`.

Comment: I have some null dates in my table how to handler null dates. @TimSchmelter

Comment: @MMK: well, how you want to handle it? Should the link be visible?

Comment: @MMK Check null : if (value == null || (Convert.ToDateTime(value) <= DateTime.Now))
    {
        return false;
    } return true;